# Summation terms

Tags: summation, definition

If I write $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10} |a_{ij}| \ ||B||_2$$
then is it the same as $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{10} \left(|a_{ij}|\right) \right)\ ||B||_2$$
or $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{10} \left(|a_{ij}| \ ||B||_2\right)\right)$$

In other words, does $\sum$ only take the left most term, all terms, or is it ambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your terms with the parentheses are correct, since $\|B\|_2$ is independent of the summations anyhow. All three of the terms you gave are the same as
$$ \|B\|_2 \sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10} |a_{ij}|$$

Comment: But doesn't the second one take $i=1..10$ = $10$ times of $||B||_2$ whereas the first one only takes it once?

Comment: Sort of...though the version I gave also "takes it 10 times"...when you pull the factor $\|B\|_2$ in front of the two sums you are making use of the distributivity of multiplication...

Comment: Yes, I just worked it out by hand and see it is the same